# Making Custom Field Required WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Please bear with me if I am not asking this question correctly. I am trying to modify a WooCommerce custom field to make it required.

The function is below:

```
public function delivery_checkout_field( $checkout )
    {
        echo '<div class="checkout-delivery" id="delivery_checkout_field">';
        echo '<input class="js-picker-object" type="hidden" value="' . esc_attr( json_encode( $this->delivery_get_picker_object() ) ) . '" />';
        echo '<h3 class="with-description">' . __( 'Delivery Schedule', 'gastro-core' ) . '</h3>';
        echo '<p class="description">Enter your desired delivery time or leave blank, if you don\'t have one.</p>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_date', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array( 'delivery-field form-row-first' ),
            'label'         => __( 'Delivery Date' ),
            'placeholder'   => __( 'Enter delivery date.' ),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_date' ) );

        woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_time', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array( 'delivery-field form-row-last' ),
            'label'         => __( 'Delivery Time' ),
            'placeholder'   => __( 'Enter delivery time.' ),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_time' ) );


        echo '</div>';
    }
```

This section saves the fields.

```
// Save delivery data
    public function delivery_checkout_field_update( $order_id )
    {
        if ( !empty( $_POST['delivery_date'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta(
                $order_id,
                'Delivery Date',
                sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_date'] )
            );
        }

        if ( !empty( $_POST['delivery_time'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta(
                $order_id,
                'Delivery Time',
                sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_time'] )
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the required HTML5 attribute and other custom attributes woocommerce function has the custom_attributes option.

```
'custom_attributes' => array( 'required' => 'required' )
```